# c++ установка прокси сервера на систему

Tags: c++, ip, proxy

Здравствуйте устанавливаю включение прокси через регистр таким кодам:

```
HKEY hKey;
RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
DWORD value = 1;
RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"ProxyEnable", 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
RegCloseKey(hKey);
SendNotifyMessageW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);
```

Всё устанавливается, но не меняется ip, а как зайду в параметры->Прокси-сервер он как бы применятся и ip применятся и ползунок там становится вкл.
Не знаю как заставить работать, помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HKEY EnableKey;
RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &EnableKey, NULL);
DWORD value = 1;
RegSetValueExW(EnableKey, L"ProxyEnable", 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));  
RegCloseKey(EnableKey);
SendNotifyMessageW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);


HKEY ProxyServerKey;
RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &ProxyServerKey, NULL);
_TCHAR szTestString[] = _T("51.89.32.83:3128");
RegSetValueExW(ProxyServerKey, L"ProxyServer", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)szTestString, sizeof(szTestString));
RegCloseKey(ProxyServerKey);
SendNotifyMessageW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);

cout << "Stop!\n";
cin.get();

system("MicrosoftEdge.exe http://yandex.ru");

system("start chrome.exe https://2ip.ru/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл пока что такой способ решения. Прокси сервер применяется так же когда запустишь бразуер "Microsoft Edge" и решение осталось одно просто запускать автоматически "Microsoft Edge" и тогда прокси заработает, как бы применится

Comment: Приведите код, как вы запускаете браузер